# Powershell outputting hash comparison results

Tags: powershell, hash, output, comparison

I'm working on a Powershell script that compares the hash of two different file paths and returns a result back on whether the match or not. Here is the script so far:

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem –Path \\Server1\D$\path | foreach  {Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName}
$Target = Get-ChildItem –Path \\Server2\C$\path | foreach  {Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName}


$HashResult = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Target -Property hash -PassThru).Path



if ($Source.Hash -eq $Target.Hash) {
Write-Host 'The source and destination match.' -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
Write-Host 'The following files have differences between the source and destination: ' -ForegroundColor Red
$HashResult
}
```

It's working as written so far, and here are the results I get when running it:

```
The following files have differences between the source and destination:
\\Server2\C$\path\AnotherTestFile.rtf
\\Server2\C$\path\Pizzaisnumberone.txt
\\Server2\C$\path\MoreTestingFiles.bmp
\\Server2\C$\path\RandomFile.txt
\\Server2\C$\path\PSTESTFILE.txt
\\Server2\C$\path\TESTDIFF.txt
\\Server1\D$\path\RandomFile.txt
\\Server1\D$\path\TESTDIFF.txt
```

Here's the thing, though. I want to make the output easier to read since this will end up generating an email alert. Is there a way to divide the hash comparison result so that you can store only certain parts of it in a variable? I've tried adding the output as a whole to a variable and it worked, but that just puts me back where I started.

Here's an example of the output I'd like:

```
The following files appear in the destination folder but not in the source:
\\Server2\C$\path\AnotherTestFile.rtf
\\Server2\C$\path\Pizzaisnumberone.txt
\\Server2\C$\path\MoreTestingFiles.bmp

The following files have differences between the two paths:

\\Server2\C$\path\PSTESTFILE.txt
\\Server2\C$\path\TESTDIFF.txt
\\Server1\D$\path\RandomFile.txt
\\Server1\D$\path\TESTDIFF.txt
```

Basically, I just want to be able to mold the output into what I want instead of just having a big dump of file paths and forcing the person reading the email to have to decipher it. How would this be possible?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49240631/edit) your question to show an example of your desired output. Often, being clear on that will allow you to discern what you need to do to achieve it; even if it doesn't, it may allow others to point you in the correct direction

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I did include an example of my desired output at the end, unless you were referring to something else?

Comment: OK, I may have misunderstood; I thought that the second one was something you had achieved, but which was not entirely what you wanted. As regards separating out the non-existent files from the extant-but-mismatched files, I commend your attention to the [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6) cmdlet; if `Test-Path` fails, the file tested doesn't exist.

Comment: I've actually been messing around with Test-Path for a different part of this code, but I'm not sure how I could make it work this specific problem. How would the output of my original hash compare work with Test-Path? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting.

Comment: Test the existence of the file before you take its hash (obvious?). If the test fails (because the file doesn't exist), add it to the list of "files that exist in _a_ but not in _b_"; if it exists, proceed to computing and comparing the hashes.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Unfortunately, I don't think that would be applicable in my case. The purpose of this script will be to compare the file paths for production and disaster recovery servers, and there would be hundreds of files in these paths that would change often enough that hardcoding them into the script wouldn't be possible. Unless there's a way to get a snapshot of the path and its contents at the start of the script, then Test-Path against the other path and go from there with the differences?

Comment: Yes, that's more-or-less the technique - e.g., `foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $here)) { <# extract the server from $file and assemble a name on the other server #>; If (Test-Path $there) { <# do the hash testing #> } else { <# put it into the doesn't-exist list #> }}`

Comment: That's a great idea, I'm going to give it a shot. Thank you so much for your help!